# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined using vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, environment-variables, vite

i am facing this issue

Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at module.exports (cloudinary.js?v=2e344892:6593:34)
at ../backend/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/utils/index.js (cloudinary.js?v=2e344892:9716:56)
at __require2 (chunk-624QZG55.js?v=9b95bc90:16:50)
at ../backend/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/cloudinary.js (cloudinary.js?v=2e344892:14211:21)
at __require2 (chunk-624QZG55.js?v=9b95bc90:16:50)
at ../backend/node_modules/cloudinary/cloudinary.js (cloudinary.js?v=2e344892:14366:22)
at __require2 (chunk-624QZG55.js?v=9b95bc90:16:50)
at cloudinary.js?v=2e344892:14369:16

i am using cloudinary.js file to upload files to cloudinary and using process.env values but now i am facing this above error in console.
i have not used any env value in fronted code.
frontend and backend folder have different package.json files

i am expecting to resolve this error

Comment: Hello Yasir, please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.